# How to create a delaunayTriangulation object from an existing triangulation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, triangulation, delaunay

I have an existing triangulation (vertices `x` and `y` and connectivity matrix `tri`) and I would like to apply the `PointLocation` method of the `delaunayTriangulation` class on this existing triangulation (much like the obsolete `tsearch` function in older versions of MATLAB).

However, the `PointLocation` method obviously needs a `delaunayTriangulation` instance as input. The `delaunayTriangulation` class always seems to perform its own triangulation procedure, which results in a different connectivity matrix than the existing `tri` matrix I have, given the vertices `x` and `y`.

Is there a way to apply `PointLocation` (or something like `tsearch`) to my existing triangulation? I have Matlab 2013a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning a `triangulation` into a `delaunayTriangulation`:

- Certainly not possible for all `triangulation`s, as they don't fulfill the Delaunay property.
- Constrained Delaunay triangulation *might* work if your `trep` is well behaved, but might possibly add additional triangles and shuffle nodes:
  `delaunayTriangulation(trep.Points, trep.edges);`

Therefore I would suggest to you the following

### Workaround:

You can construct a workaround using the methods from the `triangulation` class:

```
trep = triangulation(tri, x, y);
QPs = rand(10,2); % Query points.
TI = pointLocation(trep, QPs);
```

With the homebrew function `pointLocation`:

```
function TI = pointLocation(trep, QPs)
% Find query point QPs in triangulation trep
TI = cell(size(QPs,1), 1);
for i = 1:size(QPs,1)
    barys = trep.cartesianToBarycentric((1:size(trep,1))', repmat(QPs(i,:),size(trep,1),1));
    TI{i} = find(all((0<=barys)&(barys<=1),2));
end
```

Notice that `TI` is a cell array, as for triangulations one can't be sure they are regular in the sense, that there is only one triangle/tetrahedron containing the point. The way this works is by computing the barycentric coordinates of your query points with respect to all the triangles/tetrahedra and then using these to check if the points are actually inside of them. (This is the case if all the barycentric coordinates are within `0<=bx,by,bz<=1`.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way of getting `MATLAB`'s inbuilt triangulation routines to do this for you -- as you note, they explicitly require the triangulation be Delaunay...

You might, though, be interested to look into my [`FINDTRIA` routines](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48812-findtria-spatial-queries-for-simplexes) (available from the `MATLAB` file exchange). `FINDTRIA` is a toolbox designed to perform point-location queries on arbitrary (d-dimensional) triangulations, including those that are non-Delaunay, non-convex or even overlapping, so it should deal with your triangulation as it is.

While not as fast as `MATLAB`'s inbuilt `pointLocation` routines (when the underlying triangulation is Delaunay), `FINDTRIA` is typically much more efficient than doing a brute-force `O(n*m)` search through each point/triangle pair. `FINDTRIA` makes use of a geometric search tree -- [an AABB-tree](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48833-aabbtree-a-d-dimensional-bounding-box-tree) -- to speed up the computations.

As of `R2014b`, `MATLAB` also supports queries on non-Delaunay triangulations using the `pointLocation` routine, though my initial experience seems to suggest that this new inbuilt function can be quite slow when the triangulation is not Delaunay...

Comment: seems to be a very useful toolbox, thanks for the info!